# How to convert timestamp variable into readable with existing script? (provided)

Tags: php, mysql

How to use this script to pass a variable into the time conversion instead of the current time?
My variable is `$article['timestamp'];` and it is a MySQL timestamp.

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');

  setlocale(LC_TIME, 'el_GR.UTF-8');
  echo strftime('%A ');
  $greekMonths = array('Ιανουαρίου','Φεβρουαρίου','Μαρτίου','Απριλίου','Μαΐου','Ιουνίου','Ιουλίου','Αυγούστου','Σεπτεμβρίου','Οκτωβρίου','Νοεμβρίου','Δεκεμβρίου');
  $greekDate = date('j') . ' ' . $greekMonths[intval(date('m'))-1] . ' ' . date('Y');
  echo $greekDate;
?>
```

**Example**

```
$article['timestamp'] = 2015-04-06 15:14:24
expected output: 06 _MONTH_ 2015. _MONTH_ is from the $greekMonths
```

Comment: Please make an example like: input, current output and expected output

Comment: You never use `$article['timestamp']` in your code. But if I understand it right you just want to replace the month with the greek month and also change it to the expected format?

Comment: @Rizier123 yes, exactly. The code I posted shows the info but in the current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert that timestamp of yours to unix timestamp and feed it into the `date()` function:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');
$article['timestamp'] = '2015-03-07 15:14:24';
$unix = strtotime($article['timestamp']); // to unix
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'el_GR.UTF-8');
echo strftime('%A ');
$greekMonths = array('Ιανουαρίου','Φεβρουαρίου','Μαρτίου','Απριλίου','Μαΐου','Ιουνίου','Ιουλίου','Αυγούστου','Σεπτεμβρίου','Οκτωβρίου','Νοεμβρίου','Δεκεμβρίου');

// then use the unix timestamp and feed it into the date function
$greekDate = date('j', $unix) . ' ' . $greekMonths[intval(date('m', $unix))-1] . ' ' . date('Y', $unix);
echo $greekDate;
```

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos sure, glad this shed some light